# Стрельба при использовании джойстика, Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Делаю мобильный топ-даун шутер под андроид.
Игрок стреляет по нажатию на экран, ходит с помощью джойстика. Стрельба реализована через `Input.touches`, для джойстика использую `CnControls` 
[image: Иллюстрация:]

При отводе пальца от джойстика происходит выстрел в точку касания. Для предотвращения стрельбы по джойстику использую `Graphics.Raycast`, т.е. касания по UI не вызывают выстрела. В данном случае пользователь не касается UI, но все равно использует его.
 Вот фрагмент кода:

```
private bool CanShoot(Vector2 position)
    {
        // Проверяем, можно ли стрелять по заданной точке экрана
        PointerEventData pointerData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);

        pointerData.position = position;

        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
        EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointerData, results);

        return results.Count == 0;
    }
```

Где-то в недрах метода `Update()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
{
    if (CanShoot(Input.touches[i].position) && (Time.time - lastShootTime) > shotCooldown)
    {  
        lastShootTime = Time.
        Shoot(Input.touches[i].position);
        break;
    }
}
```

Как все исправить?

Comment: `касания по UI не вызывают выстрела` -- вы уверены, что именно режутся касания по интерфейсу? По-моему, луч просто игнорирует UI, и работает с графикой ПОД ним

Comment: Эм, ну хз... Я немного новичок, так что может быть я не прав, но Graphic.Raycast делает тоже что и обычный raycast только с UI. Но главное - оно работает - нажатие непосредственно на джойстик не вызывают выстрела

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ.
В код нужно добавить проверку фазы касания:

```
if (Input.touches[i].phase == TouchPhase.Began && CanShoot(Input.touches[i].position) && (Time.time - lastShootTime) > shotCooldown)
{  
    lastShootTime = Time.
    Shoot(Input.touches[i].position);
    break;
}
```

Так как чтобы начать движение нужно коснуться джойстика, касания начавшиеся на джойстике будут отсеиваться методом CanShoot.

Стоит заметить, что этот метод может не работать если у джойстика включено свойство SnapsToFinger.